# How to split a section in a list?

Tags: python, list

Okay so I have a list called names and there are other words in the list but this is the result of names[0]

```
Chen,David,M,334791530,,11Z,,16770712,,,,,,00015956753,
Chen,Peter,M,321564726,,11B,,19979810,,,,,,00012446698,
Chung,Rowan,M,32355988,,11T,,17890708,,,,,,00012127821,
Chung,Kyle,M,387638355,,10U,,19970317,,,,,,00015604870,
Fan,Mark,M,34217543,,10U,,19707713,,,,,,00015799079,
```

How do I split names[0] so that it comes out with just the last name, first name, and gender?

Here's the rest of my code:

```
file = open('CASS.txt', 'r')
f = file.readlines()
file.close()
for line in f:
    if line.find('ICS3M105')>=0:
        names = line.split()
        for name in names[0]:
            if name in range(0,1):
                print(names)
```

Comment: Three side notes: (1) `line.find('ICS3M105')>=0` is a lot more readable as `'IC3SM105' in line`. (2) `if name in range(0,1)` basically means `if name == 0`, and given that `name` is a string, it's always going to be false. (3) There's no reason for `readlines` here. Just loop `for line in file:` before closing the file. (Also, use a `with` statement to get rid of the explicit `close`.)

Comment: Also, if you want to parse CSV files, look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. `for row in csv.reader(file):` will give you a list of `(last, first, sex, somenumber, '', somecode, '', someothernumber, …)` for each `row`, without you having to do any extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in f:
  names = line.split()
  print names[0].split(',')[0:3]
```

Comment: you can just do `[:3]` instead of `[0:3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('CASS.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name_last, name_first, gender = line.split(',')[0:3]
```

Or using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which will may be more reliable for upcoming tasks

```
import csv
with open('CASS.txt', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        name_last, name_first, gender = row[0:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = """Chen,David,M,334791530,,11Z,,16770712,,,,,,00015956753,
           Chen,Peter,M,321564726,,11B,,19979810,,,,,,00012446698,
           Chung,Rowan,M,32355988,,11T,,17890708,,,,,,00012127821,
           Chung,Kyle,M,387638355,,10U,,19970317,,,,,,00015604870,
           Fan,Mark,M,34217543,,10U,,19707713,,,,,,00015799079,"""
```

You can use a list comprehension to split on commas, then use slicing to index element `[0]` to `[2]` (inclusive) of the `split` operation.

```
>>> [i.split(',')[:3] for i in s.split('\n')]
[['Chen', 'David', 'M'],
 ['Chen', 'Peter', 'M'],
 ['Chung', 'Rowan', 'M'],
 ['Chung', 'Kyle', 'M'],
 ['Fan', 'Mark', 'M']]
```